# Minecraft clickable held item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am making a server and I am trying to make clickable items that will bring up other menus to select the server or item etc. How can I do this

Answer (score 1):

You can create a chest gui with a [Minecraft datapack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOuRyx0Ipe4), but it isn't always the easiest.

If you're using a Spigot-like server, you can use different plugins to create a chest gui menu system ([example spigot plugin](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/bettergui.75620/)). Skript might also be able to [make](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TC9L5D2oPOw) this with the Tuske addon.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to program anything [Command Panels](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/command-panels-custom-guis.67788/) is a plugin that allows you to create Minecraft Chest GUIs provided you have a [Spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org/) (or Spigot compatible, such as [Paper](https://papermc.io/) which is easier to set up) server.